# Coda Slider Issue IE 9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9, coda-slider

i've got a problem with the popular Coda Slider 2.0 on the Internet Explorer 9. It just doens't load. No Problems on IE 7 (haven't tested IE 8 yet), Firefox, Safari or Chrome.

That's my call:

```
$('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
    dynamicArrows: false,
    dynamicTabs: false,
    autoHeight: true,
    slideEaseDuration: 500,
    firstPanelToLoad: 1
});
```

Here you can find the website: [formular.luzsolar.de](http://formular.luzsolar.de)

Are there any known issues with IE9? Pretty hard to find some information about it, google wasn't very helpfull yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take an jQuery update to version v1.6.1

try it!